# How do i create a radio button with a check mark on a tableview cell in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

My goal is to achieve this screen

[image]

**TableView Controller**

```
import UIKit

class MatchFriendsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {
    private let contacts = ContactAPI.getContacts()
    
    private let contactsTableView: UITableView = {
        let contactsTableView = UITableView()
        contactsTableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contactsTableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
        contactsTableView.rowHeight = 70
        contactsTableView.register(ContactTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "contactCell")
        return contactsTableView
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        contactsTableView.dataSource = self
        view.addSubview(contactsTableView)
        
        addConstraint()
        setupNavigation()
    }
    
    private func addConstraint() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            contactsTableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            contactsTableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
            contactsTableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
            contactsTableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor)
        ])
    }
    
    func setupNavigation() {
        let nextBarItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Next", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(nextBarItemButton))
        navigationItem.title = "Add Friends"
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nextBarItem
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.tintColor = .white
        let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
        appearance.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 252/255, green: 114/255, blue: 15/255, alpha: 1)
        let titleAttribute = [NSAttributedString.Key.font:  UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: .bold), NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
        appearance.titleTextAttributes = titleAttribute
        navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance = appearance
        navigationController?.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
        
    }

    @objc func nextBarItemButton() {
        
    }
        
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return contacts.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "contactCell", for: indexPath) as! ContactTableViewCell
        cell.nameLabel.text = contacts[indexPath.row].name
        cell.profileImageView.image = UIImage(named: "1")
        
        return cell
    }
}
```

**TableView Cell**

```
import UIKit

class ContactTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    let profileImageView: UIImageView = {
        let image = UIImageView()
        image.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        image.layer.cornerRadius = 30
        image.clipsToBounds = true
        return image
    }()
    
    let nameLabel: UILabel = {
        let nameLabel = UILabel()
        nameLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: .medium)
        nameLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return nameLabel
    }()
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        contentView.addSubview(profileImageView)
        contentView.addSubview(nameLabel)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            profileImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
            profileImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 10),
            profileImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor),
            profileImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
            profileImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
            
            nameLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileImageView.topAnchor, constant: 10),
            nameLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileImageView.trailingAnchor, constant: 20),
           
        ])
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
       super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

The result that I got

[image]

How do i add a similar radio button like in the picture above? should i add it in cellForRowAt?

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "contactCell", for: indexPath) as! ContactTableViewCell
        cell.nameLabel.text = contacts[indexPath.row].name
        cell.profileImageView.image = UIImage(named: "1")
        
        return cell
    }
```

**Updated**

After I implemented Abishek's answer

[image]

```
import UIKit

class ContactTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    let profileImageView: UIImageView = {
        let image = UIImageView()
        image.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        image.layer.cornerRadius = 30
        image.clipsToBounds = true
        return image
    }()
    
    let nameLabel: UILabel = {
        let nameLabel = UILabel()
        nameLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: .medium)
        nameLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return nameLabel
    }()
    
    let checkBox: CheckBox = {
       let checkBox = CheckBox()
        checkBox.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return checkBox
    }()
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        contentView.addSubview(profileImageView)
        contentView.addSubview(nameLabel)
        contentView.addSubview(checkBox)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            profileImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
            profileImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 10),
            profileImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor),
            profileImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
            profileImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
            
            nameLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileImageView.topAnchor, constant: 10),
            nameLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileImageView.trailingAnchor, constant: 20),
            
            checkBox.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor),
            checkBox.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -20),
            checkBox.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30),
            checkBox.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30),
        ])
    }
    
    func updateCheckState(_ isSelected: Bool) {
        checkBox.isChecked = isSelected
    }
    
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
       super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

Comment: You can add a `SFymbol` (`checkmark.circle.fill` for the filled) and ini the view, depending on the state, change the image

Comment: Thanks for the response. Where do i add the checkmark? in one of the tableView delegate?

Answer (score 0):

Since, we don't have any default checkbox component in `UIKIt`, you need create your own and then reuse it in your `UITableViewCell`--

1. Write Checkbox.swift something like this -

```
import UIKit

class Checkbox: UIButton {
    // This will handle the state of Checkbox
    var isChecked: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            if isChecked {
                self.setImage(UIImage(named: "img-check"), for: .normal)
            } else {
                self.setImage(UIImage(named: "img-uncheck"), for: .normal)
            }
        }
    }
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.tintColor = UIColor.blue //TODO:
        self.isChecked = false
        self.addTarget(self, action:#selector(buttonClicked(sender:)), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)
    }

    @objc func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
       if sender == self { isChecked = !isChecked } 
    }
```

And, then in your `UITableViewCell` --

```
import UIKit

class UserTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var profileImahe: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var checkButton: Checkbox!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        self.tintColor = UIColor.white
        
        //updateImage()
    }
    
    func updateCheckState(_ isSelected: Bool) {
        checkButton.isChecked = isSelected
    }
    
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()

        self.profileImahe.image = nil
        // updateImage()
    }
}
```

And, next you will use this in your View Layer -

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataSource.count ?? 0
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 80
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "UserTableViewCell") as! UserTableViewCell
        cell.labelTitle.text = dataSource[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! UserTableViewCell
        cell.updateCheckState(true)
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! UserTableViewCell
        cell.updateCheckState(false)
    }
```

FYI, [image]

Comment: Hey Abishek i've implemented your answer. Unfortunately I have to click the cell in order for the button to appear. I've updated the image in my question. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @airsoftFreak, 
You can get Click Selection Event on 
1. Either complete Cell
2. or, Checkbox Button itself - you can update your Checkbox.swift with following Fix

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        self.isChecked = false
        self.addTarget(self, action:#selector(buttonClicked(sender:)), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)
    }
    
    @objc func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
        if sender == self {
            isChecked = !isChecked
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you update the answer above instead? Thanks man

Comment: @airsoftFreak- I have update a line of code in Checkbox.swift